# What is the best approach for calling third-party react hooks conditionally?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

A lot of libraries in the react ecosystem now provide hooks to easily integrate into hook based react apps. One problem I've encountered is the need to conditionally call third party hooks.

```
(props)=>{
  if(condition)
   useThirdPartyHook()
}
```

The problem is you can't call hooks conditionally like the above example, so what are you supposed to do? I'm beginning to think that third-party libraries should not provide their own hooks at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `useLazyQuery` from [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/)

The `ThirdPartyHook` would need to return a function you can call later.

```
(props)=>{
  const doThisLater = useThirdPartyHook()
  if(condition) doThisLater()
}
```

If the library doesn't provide this functionality... I don't think it's written for the "lazy" use case.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to give you the answer, this is an excellent example